# Is there a CPU_time() performance penalty in Fortran?

Tags: performance, fortran

I'm working on some code which makes circa `200*steps` calls to the CPU_time() function throughout to help provide performance statistics.

However - does making these calls itself have a performance penality, given that `steps` is often up to 70 or 80 million (i.e. maybe 1500000000000 [*Correction 15 0000 0000*]  `CPU_time()` calls on a single run).

I know a totally obvious way to solve this to benchmark, but rather than faffing with that I figured I'd ask to see if anyone had any experience with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created this short fortran program to test this:

```
program cputimer
  implicit none
  integer :: i
  integer, parameter :: n = 1000000
  real(8) :: t1, t2, t
  call cpu_time(t1)
  do i = 1, n
    call cpu_time(t)
  end do
  call cpu_time(t2)
  write(*,*) (t2-t1)/n
end program
```

I ran it using gfortran on my laptop. The output was 440 ns. The overhead from the loop itself should be much less than this (replacing the `call cpu_time` in the loop with `t=1` and turning off optimization so that the loop is not optimized away, I find 3 ns per iteration, so practically all the time is spent in `cpu_time`), so I think this is a reasonable estimate of the time it takes to perform one call to cpu_time. How significant this is depends on how long the rest of your code takes. 1500000000000*440ns = 7.6 days, so it sounds like it could be very significant. But 1.5 trillion calls is not consistent with the numbers you gave above (75 million steps with 200 calls per step gives 15 billion calls, which would then take 1.8 hours. Still quite a lot.

You might not need to call `cpu_time` that often, though. One easy way to speed this up is to only call it every Nth step in the iteration, which will give you a speedup of a factor of N. I was also going to suggest using `mpi_wtime`, which is fast and has a higher quality clock than `cpu_time`, but it turns out to be almost twice as slow as `cpu_time`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this - I was being rushed out the lab but just wanted to throw this out. Great result and great solution - 10/10!